# I need to trigger change function whenever a text in dropdown list is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jquery code is having two dropdown boxes,one containing country and the other one holds currency.so here i want that whenever a country is selected in the box it will trigger a change function that will perform some comparison using if-else and will select the currency in the other dropdown and leaving it as 'disabled' to true.Below is my code for the same:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $(".select").change(function () {
                debugger;
               
                var c = $('#country :selected').text();
                if (c == 'india') {
                    $('select[name="currency"]').find('option[value="1"]').attr("selected", true);
                    document.getElementById('disable').disabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('select[name="currency"]').find('option[value="2"]').attr("selected", true);
                    document.getElementById('disable').disabled = true;
                }
            });

        });
       //$(function () {
       //    var select = $('select.select');
       //    select.change(function () {
       //        select.not(this).val(this.value);
       //        document.getElementById("disable").disabled = true;
       //    });
       //});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="country" id="country" class="select">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">india</option>
            <option value="2">America</option>
        </select>
        <select name="currency" id="disable" class="select">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">INR</option>
            <option value="2">DOLLAR</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but now the problem is when i select india it shows IR which is ok and then when i select America,it shows Doller and finally the problem comes now,when i again change the country back to india the change function is not called at all and dollar gets remain selected and disabled.Fix this it would be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

With `.attr`, both the `options` have `selected` attribute set hence browser fail to make out which option to be set as `selected`.

From [*docs*](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName), **To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.** *(`.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior.)*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select").change(function() {
    var c = $('#country :selected').text();
    if (c == 'india') {
      $('select[name="currency"]').find('option[value="1"]').prop("selected", true);
    } else {
      $('select[name="currency"]').find('option[value="2"]').prop("selected", true);
    }
    document.getElementById('disable').disabled = true;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="country" id="country" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">india</option>
    <option value="2">America</option>
  </select>
  <select name="currency" id="disable" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">INR</option>
    <option value="2">DOLLAR</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: great!Thank you:)

Comment: @KamalSingh – Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 0):

Since the values on both `select` are the same. You can easily set the value of the second `select` based on the first.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.select').on('change',function() {
    var val = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    $('[name=currency]').val( val ).attr('disabled',true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="country" id="country" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">india</option>
    <option value="2">America</option>
  </select>
  <select name="currency">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="1">INR</option>
    <option value="2">DOLLAR</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the above answer you can use the "$" jquery selector instead of `document.getElementById`

Plus note you can use `.prop('disabled', false);`
too, like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select").change(function() {
    var c = $('#country :selected').text();
    if (c == 'india') {
      $('select[name="currency"]').find('option[value="1"]').prop("selected", true);
    } else {
      $('select[name="currency"]').find('option[value="2"]').prop("selected", true);
    }
    $(#'disable').prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```